# Handle click event on a flash banner

Tags: jquery, flash, click

I want to handle the click event on a flash banner. The flash banner is a link to another page.

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.banner').click(function () {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');

          alert(id);
        });   
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a id="banner_1" class="banner" href="http://google.com">
      <h1>Banner 1</h1>
    </a>

      <embed id="test_1" class="banner" src="http://www.dg/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/sera-flash_web-banner_preset.swf" 
          width="400" 
          height="120" 
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      />       

    <a id="banner_2" class="banner" href="http://yahoo.com">
      <h1>Banner 2</h1>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

Edit

Also i try to add onclick, onrelease event as follows. but it not working.

```
 <embed onrelease="alert('ddd');" src="http://www.dlk/stg/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/sera-flash_web-banner_preset.swf" 
          width="400" 
          height="120" 
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      />
```

Comment: what exactly is your goal?

Comment: I want save banner click in database. so i want do it in banner click event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of JavaScript you can use CSS. Inject an absolute positioned DIV above the embed, and set the z-index higher them the embed.